# Global hotkey taking exclusive use of keys

Tags: c#, winforms, hotkeys, registerhotkey, global-hotkey

I'm currently using this code for hotkey manager that i found on another post here:

```
public class HotKeyReader
    {
        public static event EventHandler<HotKeyEventArgs> HotKeyPressed;

        public static int RegisterHotKey(Keys key, KeyModifiers modifiers)
        {
            int id = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _id);
            RegisterHotKey(_wnd.Handle, id, (uint)modifiers, (uint)key);
            return id;
        }

        public static bool UnregisterHotKey(int id)
        {
            return UnregisterHotKey(_wnd.Handle, id);
        }

        protected static void OnHotKeyPressed(HotKeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (HotKeyReader.HotKeyPressed != null)
            {
                HotKeyReader.HotKeyPressed(null, e);
            }
        }

        private static MessageWindow _wnd = new MessageWindow();

        private class MessageWindow : Form
        {
            protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            {
                if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
                {
                    HotKeyEventArgs e = new HotKeyEventArgs(m.LParam);
                    HotKeyReader.OnHotKeyPressed(e);
                }

                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }

            private const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x312;
        }

        [DllImport("user32")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

        private static int _id = 0;
    }


    public class HotKeyEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public readonly Keys Key;
        public readonly KeyModifiers Modifiers;

        public HotKeyEventArgs(Keys key, KeyModifiers modifiers)
        {
            this.Key = key;
            this.Modifiers = modifiers;
        }

        public HotKeyEventArgs(IntPtr hotKeyParam)
        {
            uint param = (uint)hotKeyParam.ToInt64();
            Key = (Keys)((param & 0xffff0000) >> 16);
            Modifiers = (KeyModifiers)(param & 0x0000ffff);
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum KeyModifiers
    {
        Alt = 1,
        Control = 2,
        Shift = 4,
        Windows = 8,
        NoRepeat = 0x4000
    }
```

But when a hotkey is registered, for example, just using "a", you can no longer use "a" anywhere else in windows. Is there anyway to stop this from happening? Or is there a better code out there that does the same.

Comment: What did you expect a *global* hotkey to do?

Comment: Well on programs such as Mumble, keyboard shortcuts work anywhere and don't take exclusive use. That is what im trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean they "work anywhere" but "don't take exclusive use"? Isn't that a contradiction? Do you actually want a shortcut that works anywhere *inside your program*?

Comment: I mean they work when the program is unfocused, But I can still use the assigned key for that shortcut anywhere else such as notepad. But on mine I cant use an assigned key anywhere else.

Comment: If you are in notepad, then your app is unfocused. You press a shortcut key. Does it go to notepad, or your app?

Comment: It goes to my app. If i used a key like A, then A will not enter into notepad, but the short cut will trigger on my app.

Comment: So what do you want to happen?

Comment: I want to be able to still use an assigned key in other programs, Not my App take exclusive use of them.

Comment: Then how will the key work when your app is unfocused?

Comment: Like how Mumble is able to, or Spofity with media keys.

Comment: I don't use those programs. If Mumble is running in the background, and you're in Notepad, and you press a hotkey assigned to Mumble, what happens?

Comment: Lets say I was using "a" again, When I press "a" the shortcut fires on Mumble and "a" gets entered into notepad.

Comment: Finally, I understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A keyboard hook, installed with `SetWindowsHook`, would allow observing the keystroke without affecting its delivery to the application.

Comment: How would I go about using that instead to perform like the code above, Never dealt with Windows hooks before.

Comment: @Tristan: You might read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx but I would try to find a library that already takes care of the details.